# ruby on rails - reset password - override

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, reset-password

I am using ruby on rails version `4.2.4` and devise `4.0.0`

I have problems with reset password and I am trying to override and reset to the new password by overriding devise myself. Now that I have the code to change password, i need to complete the "update" function.

Below is my code to override Devise::PasswordsController

in route.rb:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { passwords: 'users/passwords' }
```

in controller/users/password_controller.rb

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

    def create
        super
        puts "create PasswordsController"
    end

    def new
        super
        puts "new PasswordsController"
    end

    def update

        reset_password_token_hash = Devise.token_generator.digest(self, :reset_password_token, resource_params['reset_password_token']) 
        user = User.find_by_reset_password_token(reset_password_token_hash)
        user.update(password: resource_params['password'])  
        #xxxx respond_with resource, needs to do something like this ??


    end

    def edit
        super
        puts "edit PasswordsController"
    end
end
```

it manage to change password but has problem with the page:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 176ms (ActiveRecord: 13.0ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template users/passwords/update, users/passwords/update, devise/passwords/update, devise/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :slim, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/megasap/Documents/project/harta.org/harta.org-backend/app/views"
  * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ckeditor-4.2.2/app/views"
  * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/grape-swagger-rails-0.2.0/app/views"
  * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.0.0/app/views"
```

Can someone let me know how to complete the "update" method for Users::PasswordsController

Comment: You can obtain a password like this because it shouldn't be that easy to get someone's password from the console or else it will be so easy to hack people.
So console isn't the best place to see if what you did is working.

Comment: ok i manage to do the override and change password, but there is still some error to respond/return, can you help me to complete the "update" code. thank you